# How to preload custom fonts with webpack/rails 6

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, webpack, fonts, web-performance

I would like to preload a custom font. I'm using rails 6 with webpack.

In config/_fonts.scss :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'customfont';
  src: font-url('customfont.eot?81236734');
  src: font-url('customfont.eot?81236734#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       font-url('customfont.woff2?81236734') format('woff2'),
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

I import this font in my application scss :

`@import "config/index";`

But I would like to preload this font. What's the best pratice to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken you have to add a link tag in head of the view as per this article : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content

Then for the href use the `asset_pack_url` helper in order to point to the right file.

Also be careful the `asset_path_url` needs to point to the folder where your compiled asset resides without mentionning "public/packs"

Then you probably have to use something like `<%= asseet_pack_url 'media/fonts/my-font.woff' %>` or something like that

(Also I am considering you are using Webpack to deliver images/css and fonts. If you are using the asdset pipeline just use the usual helpers)

Answer (score 1):

Recently had same question. Here is what I did for Rails 6 with webpack.
Per my understanding webpack produces `manifest.json` which you can find in public directory of your app (it is configured in `webpacker.yml`).

When you open manifest.json you should also see references for fonts.
In my manifest it appeared similar to the following:

```
"media/images/some-font.woff2": "/packs/media/images/4d419d560889218c146f.woff2"
```

Now when you know that the pack path is available, it is easy to construct preloading in head section (example in haml):

```
= preload_link_tag(asset_pack_path('media/images/some-font.woff2'))
```